# Why isn’t the fundamental theorem of algebra violated in $\mathbb{Z} \mod m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Why isn’t the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra violated when working in Z mod m? For example, $x^2+5x$ in Z mod 6 has more than 2 solutions.

Comment: Because the statement is about complex polynomials and their solutions in $\mathbb{C}$. You cannot just change the ring and expect arbitrary statements to hold. Especially not, if you change from an algebraically closed field to a ring which is not even a domain.

Comment: $\mathbb Z / (6)$ is not even a field.

Comment: @TMO said it really well. As I tell my calculus students, 'where' is as important as 'what'.

Comment: Theorems have hypotheses, not just conclusions. The hypotheses of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra are not satisfied in the integers modulo six, so there's no reason to expect the conclusion to apply.

Answer (score 3):

The statement that the number of roots of a polynomial of degree $n$ is at most $n$ is not the fundamental theorem of algebra (which is about complex polynomials and claims something much stronger), and it is true only for polynomials over an integral domain. The ring $\mathbb{Z}/6$ is not a domain because $2*3=0$ there.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^2+5x$ may be factorized as $x(x+5)=0$.  Over a field you could conclude that $x=0$ or $x+5=0$ and you would get just two solutions $x=0,-5$ (unless $0=-5$ in which case you would have a repeated solution).

However over $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ this is no longer the case.  You could have $x=3$ and $x+5=2$ for example, so neither of $x$ or $x+5$ is zero, but their product is.